# последовательность операций над списком

Tags: python-3.x, list, математика

дан список чисел переменной длинны

a = [10, 45, 14, 7, 78, 90, 34]

над списком необходимо последовательно совершить математические операции:

10 + 45 - 14 * 7 / 78 + 90 - 34

именно в такой последовательности, а не в математической. Т.е. Первый элемент сложить со вторым из полученной суммы вычесть третий элемент, полученную разность умножить на четвертый элемент, на полученное произведение поделить нацело пятый элемент и т.д.

из-за того, что длинна списка может быть разной решение вида:

((((lst[0]+lst[1])-lst[2])*lst[3])/lst[4])

не подходит...
подскажите, пожалуйста простое и изящное решение...

Comment: а если длинна списка больше? какая должна быть следующая операция? они должны повторяться?

Comment: Да, если длинна списка больше пяти, снова начинаем сначала: суммируем следующий элемент, потом вычитаем следующий и так далее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаете длину, используйте цикл:

```
import itertools

a = [10, 45, 14, 7, 78, 90, 34]
ops = itertools.cycle('+-*/')

it = iter(a)
result = next(it)
for op, v in zip(ops, it):
    print(result, op, v, end=' = ')
    if op == '+':
        result += v
    if op == '-':
        result -= v
    if op == '*':
        result *= v
    if op == '/':
        result //= v
    print(result)
print(result)
```

> ```
> $ python calculator.py
> 10 + 45 = 55
> 55 - 14 = 41
> 41 * 7 = 287
> 287 / 78 = 3
> 3 + 90 = 93
> 93 - 34 = 59
> 59
> ```

Или так:

```
import itertools
import operator

a = [10, 45, 14, 7, 78, 90, 34]
ops = itertools.cycle((
    operator.add,
    operator.sub,
    operator.mul,
    operator.floordiv
))

it = iter(a)
result = next(it)
for op, v in zip(ops, it):
    print(result, op.__name__, v, end=' = ')
    result = op(result, v)
    print(result)
print(result)
```

> ```
> $ python calculator.py
> 10 add 45 = 55
> 55 sub 14 = 41
> 41 mul 7 = 287
> 287 floordiv 78 = 3
> 3 add 90 = 93
> 93 sub 34 = 59
> 59
> ```

Comment: Надо зациклить как-то наверное действия сами

Comment: @CrazyElf, поправил. Оно?

Comment: Вот теперь красиво вообще )  Хотя может там `reduce` вообще подошёл бы и можно ещё короче сделать, но я не уверен, просто мысль.

Comment: `reduce` уже в соседнем ответе.

Answer (score 3):

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv
from itertools import cycle
from functools import reduce


# Входные данные
items = [10, 45, 14, 7, 78, 90, 34]


operations = cycle([add, sub, mul, truediv])  # зацикленные операторы +-*/

func = lambda x, y: next(operations)(x, y)

result = reduce(func, items)

print(result)
```